# Reading data from a thread ( in a Servlet)

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm using the ServletContextListener to create a new thread.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

    public class Port implements ServletContextListener {
        private ExecutorService executor;

        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
            executor.shutdown();

        }

        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) { 
            // start task
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executor.submit(new Task()); //task should implement Runnable!

        }
    }
```

Inside this thread I'm reading data from a serial port (SerialPortEventListener). The task.class should read out information from the serial port during the whole period in which the server is active. I've thrown this inside a thread because there can only be one instance that reads from the serial port; data should then be shared to all clients.

Now I would like to acces the data this thread is reading from the serial port.

Can this be done? And if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, for example, store the read data in a servlet context attribute. Then, from the other classes, you would get the attribute from the servlet context:

```
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event) { 
        // start task
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String data = readFromPort();
                event.getServletContext().setAttribute("serialPortData", data); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean servlet context attribute?

Comment: I really have a lot of sensor data; do you think it would be efficient thing to do compared to the other presented solutions (callback)?

Comment: You didn't tell which information the servlet should have access to, and when. If the data is contantly modified, I suggest you put an object containing the data that needs to be accessed in a servlet context attribute (as a custom object). Update the object from the thread, and get the data from the servlet. Make sure everything is thread-safe.

Comment: in the servlet's I'll have to use a timer for reading out the context attribute? Thx this sound like a good idea. Apparently java doesn't have callback functions so this look to be the better idea.

Comment: Why would you use a timer? You update the data from the thread started in the contextInitialized methd. And in the servlet, you read the data from the attribute. Why would you need a timer? WHat do you want to do in the servlet exactly?

Comment: If the data changes I want to send the updated data to the connected clients. I forgot to tell you that I'm using websockets (fallback to long-polling). So I have a full duplex connection. When new data is recieved over the serial port I want to push it to all connected clients.

Comment: Thx; Is there a reason why servlet context attribute is not a good idea anymore?

Comment: It's still a good idea. You would put a BlockingQueue in a servlet context attribute.

Comment: So I just call in my SerialReader constructor: event.getServletContext().setAttribute("serialPortData", queue); And when I get new data I call queue.add

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done, and you have few options:

1- Using a shared `concurrent.BlockingQueue` where inside the thread add new data from the `SerialPort` and in your servlet read from that queue

2- Have an event listener object inside your servlet and pass it in your `task` constructor. The listener object should have a callback function that is invoked when `SerialEvent` occur.

In general, this is a typical *producer/consumer* pattern

Comment: I guess using a serial event listener inside the servlet sound like the better idea. However I'm a bit new with java. Implementing the serial event listener is probably going to work but how do I pass this information to the servlet? Just trough a parameter from the callback?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to share the data in the new Runnable you're going to create. You can add to it a [concurrent collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html).